# In my query MYSQL CAST not working

Tags: mysql, enums, casting

I don't know what is wrong in my MYSQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM package_customers pc 
left join installations ins on ins.package_customer_id = pc.id 
WHERE pc.status = 'scheduled' 
AND CAST(ins.schedule_date as DATE) >='10-27-2017'
```

The fields are:

1. status data type enum
2. schedule_date data type varchar

In the column `schedule_date`, the  data is like this: `10-27-2017 12AM  12PM`

I am trying to find date-wise data.

Comment: What is your question? What result did this query provide? How did that different from what you want?

Comment: In my database field schedule_date have  10-27-2017 12AM  12PM and status field have  scheduled  but when I run this query message is: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0242 sec)

Comment: Don't put essential info in comments; they should be considered ephemeral. Instead, [edit] your question to contain all relevant info that readers need to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cast` function can work if the source data is in acceptable format.
There are some conditions to validate `date and time` formats.
Your `schedule_date` column value does not match them. And hence, `cast` failed.
Please read [documentation on ***Date and Time Types***](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html).

You should think of redesigning the table to include `schedule_start` and `schedule_end` columns with `datetime` data type. MySQL has various [date and time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to work with such data fields.

For time being, your varchar date data can be handled in following way.

```
mysql> SELECT @dt_string:='10-27-2017 12AM  12PM' AS dt_string
    ->      , @dtime:=STR_TO_DATE( @dt, '%m-%d-%Y %h%p %h%p' ) AS date_time
    ->      , DATE( @dtime ) AS my_date;
+-----------------------+---------------------+------------+
| dt_string             | date_time           | my_date    |
+-----------------------+---------------------+------------+
| 10-27-2017 12AM  12PM | 2017-10-27 12:00:00 | 2017-10-27 |
+-----------------------+---------------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```